# Get /dev/<whatever> of USB drive containing running C++ executable

Tags: c++

I have a C++ program. It's on a USB drive. How can I figure out the /dev path of this USB drive? (from the current running program)

Comment: argc[0] should have the full executable path. But then you'll have to rummage around with mapping that executable path to the mounted filesystems

Comment: That's actually wrong. First, you meant argv[0]. Second, it won't have the full path unless the executable was launched as a full path. If it was launched as a ./ (from the present directory) you won't have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're on Linux (you didn't specify which OS) - You can get your full executable path by looking at /proc/self/exe - note that checking argv[0] won't work here (reason described above).

/proc/self/exe is a symbolic link to the full exectuable path. "self" is a symbolic link to your own pid, so you don't have to worry about that it is. Example:

```
[root@localhost frameworks]# ls -l /proc/self/exe
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Feb 14 18:00 /proc/self/exe -> /usr/bin/ls
```

Note 'ls' sees itself here. Different processes would likewise see their full paths.

Then, what you would need to do is get the list of mounted file systems (in the same way that mount(1) does, using getmntent(3)), and find the longest mount point path (the mnt_dir field of the entry structure) which is a prefix of your exe name. This is from mntent.h:

```
struct mntent {
           char *mnt_fsname;   /* name of mounted file system */
           char *mnt_dir;      /* file system path prefix */
           char *mnt_type;     /* mount type (see mntent.h) */
           char *mnt_opts;     /* mount options (see mntent.h) */
           int   mnt_freq;     /* dump frequency in days */
           int   mnt_passno;   /* pass number on parallel fsck */
       };
```

Comment: Can you describe this a bit more, maybe some examples?

Comment: Just added examples, too.

Comment: Awesome, this is great, but what do I pass as `FILE *fp`?

also, yes, I'm on UNIX :)

Comment: That, my friend, is in the man page: The  getmntent()  function  reads  the  next  line from the file system description file fp and returns a
       pointer to a structure containing the broken out fields from a line in the file.  The pointer points to a
       static area of memory which is overwritten by subsequent calls to getmntent(). - so pass a pointer to the /etc/mtab file.

Comment: yeah, I was reading that. Do I pass the USB mount point (e.g. `/mnt` if I ran `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`)? (oh, ok, I was wrong)

Comment: but what if there are multiple mounts? then how do get each mount?

Comment: getmntent will give you one line at a time from /etc/mtab. You then have to look at the mnt_dir to see if that matches the executable path. i.e you have to iterate over all of the lines returned.

Comment: can you give an example of iterating over the lines (sorry for bugging you for examples)

Comment: Dude, that's a simple for() loop, or while getmntent returns something which isnt NULL.  Any more than that is like writing the program for you. And I think that's against StackOVerFlow rules, (and they are already warning this is an extended discussion we should avoid, or something)